# Scrapy - Getting duplicated items when appending items using for loop

Tags: json, scrapy

I am crawling the data from JSON response. Extracting data into item using for loop and all i get, is a last record rewriting all the previous records made by this loop.

Here is my code:

```
def parse_centers_and_ambulances(self, response):
    json_response = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    facility = MedFacilityItem()
    facility["name"] = "Med Facility #1"
    centers = []
    med_centers = MedCenterItem()
    for center in json_response:
      if center["name"].startswith("Center"):
        med_centers["response_url"] = center["product_id"]
        med_centers["name"] = center["name"]
        med_centers["address"] = center["name_short"] + "." +     
                                               center["adr_name"] + " " + 
                                               center["adr_dom"]
        med_centers["lat"] = center["latitude"]
        med_centers["lon"] = center["longitude"]
        med_centers["phoneInfo"] = [{"number": center["tel1"],
                                     "description": center["tel1_descr"]},
                                    {"number": center["tel2"],
                                     "description": center["tel2_descr"]}]
        centers.append(med_centers)

    facility["facility_type"] = centers
    return facility
```

What i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Scrapy items basically behave like dicts, I'm going to use dicts for the following examples. Consider this:

```
In [1]: dict_list = []
   ...: d = {}
   ...: for i in range(3):
   ...:     d['i'] = i
   ...:     dict_list.append(d)
   ...: print dict_list
   ...: print [id(e) for e in dict_list]
   ...:
[{'i': 2}, {'i': 2}, {'i': 2}]
[4557722520, 4557722520, 4557722520]
```

Dicts are mutable objects, and in this case you are appending the *same* dict instance multiple times to a list. The resulting list does not contain different items, only several references to the same dict object. The following example shows the same behaviour, appending the same dict three times to a list and then setting a value for it:

```
In [2]: dict_list = []
   ...: d = {}
   ...: for i in range(3):
   ...:     dict_list.append(d)
   ...: d['some'] = 'value'
   ...: print dict_list
   ...:
[{'some': 'value'}, {'some': 'value'}, {'some': 'value'}]
```

What you need to do is create *different* dicts by initializing them *inside* the for loop, as follows:

```
In [3]: dict_list = []
   ...: for i in range(3):
   ...:     d = {}
   ...:     d['i'] = i
   ...:     dict_list.append(d)
   ...: print dict_list
   ...: print [id(e) for e in dict_list]
   ...:
[{'i': 0}, {'i': 1}, {'i': 2}]
[4557901904, 4557724760, 4557843264]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try defining your item inside of the loop, instead outside of it.

```
def parse_centers_and_ambulances(self, response):
    json_response = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    facility = MedFacilityItem()
    facility["name"] = "Med Facility #1"
    centers = []
    # med_centers = MedCenterItem()  <-- this 
    for center in json_response:
      if center["name"].startswith("Center"):
        med_centers = MedCenterItem()  <-- should be here
        med_centers["response_url"] = center["product_id"]
        med_centers["name"] = center["name"]
        med_centers["address"] = center["name_short"] + "." +     
                                               center["adr_name"] + " " + 
                                               center["adr_dom"]
        med_centers["lat"] = center["latitude"]
        med_centers["lon"] = center["longitude"]
        med_centers["phoneInfo"] = [{"number": center["tel1"],
                                     "description": center["tel1_descr"]},
                                    {"number": center["tel2"],
                                     "description": center["tel2_descr"]}]
        centers.append(med_centers)

    facility["facility_type"] = centers
    return facility
```